# Smoothwal 3 SP1 - Remove Access to Admin Page

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

Does anyone know an 'easy' way to disable access to the main admin page in smoothwall 3 SP 1?
I looked into the 'permissions' but nothing obvious jumped out at me; I'm trying to limit the PURPLE (wireless) interface from being able to access the administrator website (contained on the Smoothwall box).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's an option in the Advanced tab for it...

The other option is to SSH into the box and modify the listen ports for the HTTP server. I did this to change it to a different port from :81, and to change the certificate it uses.

*---update---*

Ok, I've just logged into my smoothwall box. Check the following location:

- Services

  - Remote Acces

    - Enable SSH

Then, SSH (with say Putty) into your smoothwall box using port 222 (e.g. edge.site.local:222).

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf
joe httpd.conf
```

For some reason it loads to the middle of the file, so use Page Up till you reach the top, and then edit the apache config file as you would usually to make it only listen on certain IPs.

You might need to consult your httpd.conf user manual from the apache website to sort it all out. While you're there, feel free to change ports around or point it to use a proper, signed certificate...

Answer (score 0):

Its been a little while since I used SmoothWall (I prefer IPCop and lately PFSense) but off the top of my head... couldn't this be done by creating a rule for the purple/wireless folks?

If you have a URL filter plugin installed that would be one way to go.  Otherwise you might be able to do something clever via port forwarding perhaps?